# $T_{p}\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

$T_{p}\mathbb{(R)}$ (Tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ at $p$) is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.
I have seen more generalized proofs that tangent space of any vector space $V$ is equal  to $V$, where V is an subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. but I could't understand this proof.

I know elements of $T_{p}\mathbb{(R)}$ will look like $d\phi_{p}$ (derivative of $\phi$ at $p$), where $\phi$ is a map from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. Can anyone give proper proof for $\mathbb{R}$ and higher dimensions as well?

Comment: The proof depends on how you define the tangent space.

Comment: @ Fei Li Tangent space is space of all tangent vecors. Tangent vecor I have defined as derivatives

Comment: I have one proof in my mind. Let us say, $\phi: U \to \mathbb{ R}$ be a map. $d\phi_{p}$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is on to map. So done